# Activity Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock! and timeout for HistoryRecord

Tags: android, coding-style

I have some warning in my application and i use JSoup concept,my app is working in another system,i can't do that why ?

I am getting following errors

```
1.03-26 15:11:14.296: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
2.03-26 15:11:14.893: WARN/ActivityManager(70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450e4348 com.list/.ListActivity}

3.03-26 15:11:25.831: WARN/System.err(407): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: www.dzone.com:80
and am using api 2.2 level 8emulator in sdk...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be safe: Network is enabled in the emulator? <kbd>F8</kbd> toggles it, and you can disable it in the launch configuration.

If you retrive the connection `Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(...);` instead of using the shortcut `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(...).get();` you can set the timeout for the connection before getting the document. Note that the Jsoup API doesn't use getter/setter...

And don't forget to use the protocol part (`http` or `https`) in the URL.